# How to separate and add on new filed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `<textarea>` tag with id of `text1` and three `<label>` tags I wish to populate based off the value of `text1` (hereby known as `filed1`, `filed2`, `filed3`, `filed4`).

Sample value of `text1`:

```
abcd 
12345678
```

Expected Output:

```
filed1 = a12
filed2 = b34
filed3 = c56
filed4 = d78
```

Here is the html code I have to set up the environment:

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
   <body>
      <div>
         <label>Filed1<label>
         <textarea id="text1">SRMP&#13;&#10;66505430</textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
         <label>Filed2:</label>
         <textarea id="text2"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
         <label>Filed3:</label>
         <textarea id="text3"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
         <label>Filed4:</label>
         <textarea id="text4"></textarea>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution can still be improved and is quite ugly but it works, I hope it helps.

```js
function splitText() {
  var textAreas = [];
  //Put all of the textareas into an array for easy access
  for(let i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    textAreas.push(document.getElementById(`text${i}`));
  }
  //Read the text from text1 and split it at a new line
  var text = textAreas[0].value;
  var [line1, line2] = text.split(/\r?\n/)
  for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    var combinedText = line1.substring(i, i+1) + line2.substring(i*2, (i+1)*2)
    textAreas[i].value = combinedText;
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <title></title>
   <body>
      <div>
         <label>Filed1<label>
         <textarea id="text1">SRMP&#13;&#10;66505430</textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
         <label>Filed2:</label>
         <textarea id="text2"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
         <label>Filed3:</label>
         <textarea id="text3"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div>
         <label>Filed4:</label>
         <textarea id="text4"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button onclick="splitText()">Do it!</button>
   </body>
</html>
```